# How to implement a cheapest Hotel Finder using design patterns?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

6 months ago, I gave a ThoughtWorks interview and was out in coding round.
I want to improve on my OO-design skills

I read Head First Design patterns to start with and got a basic idea of common design patterns around.
and While I am now working on iOS I am learning Objective C. and have come across various design pattern being applied via a dynamic language and getting an understanding of things.

However I still want to be sure about what would be appropriate choice of pattern used in this sample problem.

and may be some tips on how to improve such skills.

Here is the problem.

There is a Hotel chain. there are three branches LakeWood,Rosewood and xyzWood.
and all of them 4 types of rates depending on combination whether the day is a weekday,weekend and the customer is reward or regular.

user input is a series of dates  on which he wants to stay at one of the Hotels and his type.
output should be the best hotel depending upon which is the cheapest overall for the stay.
in case of a tie there will be rating for each hotel, and one with more rating decides the tie.
and program should be flexible so that new algorithm can be used to find best hotel and also if anything changes in the structure of Hotel or more Hotels are added.

I came us with following classes in terms of java.

- Hotel : having ratings,name, and 4 types of rates
- HotelFinder Interface which has a finder method which returns Hotel.
- CheapestHotelFinder class that implements this interface and has attributes like Customer or Customer type which could be an enum  [ not sure ]and a list of dates .
- Probably, A Customer class where customer details are dates n type and this customer is given to the finder.
- Is there a way that comparable interface can be used for Hotel class?
- and a Booking System Singleton class that would do all the work for us.

I am stuck here. I hope if anyone can help me out with the design.

Comment: Do Thoughworks require OO-design 'by the book'? :-O

Comment: Don't know ... but in general how would you go abt it ?

Comment: I tend to follow Einstein's rule: "Make it as simple as possible, but no simpler". Your set of classes seems ok. Did you try to actually implement them?

Comment: Actually at that time I had just started with patterns. so what I did was actually not good for sure.
So after I was out and didn't get any feedback on what went wrong.
I thought of trying this again n again.
and this is where I have reached.
Moreover.. I am still not sure where ..all these patterns are useful are all of them language independent.
specially something like Adapter, in a dynamic language where duck typing so common..is Adapter of any use ?
I still wonder why we use protocols in Obj-C ..or is it that duck typing is a bad idea ?

Comment: also.. how do Functional programming languages deal with such issues that are solved by OOPS languages using design patterns.
Factory method has so many side effects but they say it has a purpose..so..how do ppl who make SW using FP languages achieve this.

Comment: Design patterns is not a holy cow. If a pattern is useful - great. If not - don't try to screw it into your code at any cost.

Answer (score 1):

I think @root chose Strategy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) because of this statement "program should be flexible so that new algorithm can be used to find best hotel".

It seems that for each kind of hotel, there may be different ways to evaluate them, so Strategy could be a way to have different ways to evaluate each hotel.

This approach would decouple the data (Hotel beans) from the evaluation algorithm (or can we call it "the feature vector function"?).

Answer (score 0):

i think Template method pattern better suits here.
 1. create Hotel interface
 2. create 3 Hotel classes(implements Hotel interface) LakeWood,Rosewood and xyzWood

1. now create customer class and it will have series of dates also.

   here both Customer class and Hotel class both are independent.
2. now create an interface say LogicInterface which will have a method and this method will 
   be passed customer and List hotels as parameter, and will be returning cheapest hotel.
   now we will create class implementing LogicInterface.cheap hotel finding logic will be 
   in this class
   here "Template method pattern" will be used,because later on and cheapest hotel finding 
   logic is changed,we will create new class which will be implementing LogicInterface 
   and just one line change will finish our work,no where any code change will be needed.